# Selenium, can’t access child window / alert /?

Tags: java, selenium, window, alert

I am using selenium, java app to navigate a web page. I get to a point where if I hover over an area, I see a + magnifying glass. When I click here, it brings up a new window. This window contains the information I am after. On MacOS, this window only contains the information and a close X in upper right corner see attached.

I’ve tried  to treat this window as an “alert” (ie driver.switchTo().alert(); and get “Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert.”

I’ve tried treating as a window (ie  boolean isChildWindowOpen = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
NumberOfWindowsToBe(2)); and get “Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for number of open windows to be 2 (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval). I only get 1 window.

The HTML code I am clicking on is  == $0. I’m guessing this is related to JS doing something?

Attached is the parent window with the child overlayed and inspect data for the parent window.

[image: Parent/child with parent inspect]

Comment: @AbiSaran Unfortunately, no.

Comment: 'driver.switchTo().alert();' statement should switch the focus to alert window, in your case it is not, so this is not the normal scenario. So without checking the website, we cannot debug, can't suggest you a solution.